# Unable to boot after Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I did an upgrade on Dell precision 3520 from  18.04 to 20.04 , but I am not able to boot. I can see the Grub menu, I select Ubuntu but after I see only the Dell logo.
 I disabled secure boot. The SATA operation on AHCI. I found a post speaking about ppt but I did not found ppt in boot configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the grub menu you can edit/read the commands grub's going to execute.
There are 3 commands that are important:

```
set root='hdX,msdosX'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.X root=Y ...
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.X
```

you can remove `quiet splash` behind the linux command, so you will get more infos, what's happening during the boot.